# inequality involving tuple of operators on Hilbert spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space.

> Let $(A_1,...,A_n) \in \mathcal{L}(E)^n$, could you please help me to show that
>   $$\displaystyle\sup_{\|x\|=1}\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\| A_i^*x\|^2\bigg)\leq (4n)\displaystyle\sup_{\|x\|=1}\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n|\langle A_ix\;,\;x\rangle|^2\bigg).$$

And you for you help.

Comment: As usual with your questions: what partial results have you obtained? Why do you suppose this might be true? What evidence is there to support this claim? What, in short, have you actually tried?

Comment: This follows immediately from my answer to your other question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285471/a-numerical-radius-inequality/285476#285476

Comment: Are you sure that you are happy just with the factor $4n$ in front of the supremum on the right? If you are, you only need to consider $n=1$, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$ \|[A_1 \dots A_n]\| = \|[A_1 \dots A_n]^*\| = \left\| \left[\begin{smallmatrix} A_1^* \\ \\\vdots \\ A_n^* \end{smallmatrix}\right] \right\| = \sup_{\|x\|=1} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \|A_i^*x\|^2 \right)^{1/2}.$$

By the answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285471/a-numerical-radius-inequality/285476#285476) we have that
$$ \frac{1}{2\sqrt n} \|[A_1 \dots A_n]\| \leq \sup_{\|x\|=1} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |\langle A_ix,x\rangle|^2\right)^{1/2}. $$

Combine these two statements to get your desired inequality.

Comment: When I have some time I'll look over the result.